# Parse Detecting Sign Up Errors

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm looking to add an `UIAlertController` to show a custom error message when the user tries to sign up. I am trying to detect one of parse's errors at sign up and check whether it is that error, therefore showing a custom error message.

I've tried using this, but it always shows the wrong error message (202, 203, 125 are all of Parse's error codes for certain errors 202 = Username Taken, 203 = Email Taken, 125 = Invalid Email Address).

There are no errors in this code, just that it isn't performing the correct lines of code in its field. Is there any other way to check whether the username is taken, then the email and then whether it is a valid email address? (I've also tried querying but I always get errors in the code)

Thanks in advance, Max.

```
        let newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.username = username
        newUser.password = password
        newUser.email = finalEmail

        // Sign up the user asynchronously
        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                //Successful sign up

            } else {

                if error != 202 {

                    //UIAlertController for error Username Taken
                } else if error != 203 {
                    //UIAlertController for error Email Taken

                } else if error != 125 {
                    //UIAlertController for error Invalid Email
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` you will find that `error` is a `NSError` object. To access the error code you should use `error.code`.

Do your codes verification as follows:

```
                if error.code == 202 {

                    //UIAlertController for error Username Taken
                } else if error.code == 203 {
                    //UIAlertController for error Email Taken

                } else if error.code == 125 {
                    //UIAlertController for error Invalid Email

                }
```

Comment: I've just tried it out and, it first gives me errors saying i should add a ? in front of error. When running the app, it isn't giving the right message still. I can post my full code if needed.

Comment: please describe what is happening

Comment: So, when I run the app, I fill in all of the fields: Email, username and password. I made the username valid and the password valid, then made the email not valid. Once I run the signup action, instead of giving me the alert of "Invalid Email", I get the error for username taken.

Comment: didnt see it but you were using "not equal" (!=). Just updated the answer with the changes.